# Calc financial calculations

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I've got a spreadsheet set up to record household financial transactions. One of the features I'd like to implement is a 'who owes what to whom' indicator. Simple enough with only two in the household, I had hoped, but while I know what exactly I want done, I don't know the correct formula. Example below:

| Amount | Payee | For A | For B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | A | 100% | 0% |
| -50 | A | 0% | 100% |
| -10 | B | 50% | 50% |

Row by row:

- A pays $100 for self. This row should be ignored, since A is paying for something A wants.
- A pays $50 for B. B now owes A $50.
- B Pays $10 for something A and B equally share. Half the value is for B, so the other half is owed by A. A owes $5 to B
- Overall, B owes A $45

I'm looking to create two cells. One showing how much A has paid for B, and one showing how much B has paid for A. I can then take the difference of each cell to see who owes what to whom.

For the first cell, I'd need a function like `if "Column Payee"="A" AND "Column For B">0, then "Column Amount" * "Column For B"`.  Problem is, this would only work on one row. I'd need that to work across every row and add up. I could work around that by creating a new column, use an IF statement, then have a separate cell add up each column, but it would get messy. Would prefer an alternative that's a bit more elegant.

My guess is that I need to use the `SUMIFS` function. The format being `=SUMIFS(Sum Range, Range 1, Criteria 1, Range 2, Criteria 2)`.

Assuming the first cell in the above table is A1, I guess I'd start with:

`=SUMIFS(A2:A4,B2:B4,"A"...`

But then I get stumped there. `Range 2` and `Criteria 2` would only work if the only values were 0% or 100%. Since I'm trying to multiply A with D for each row, I need a different method.

Thoughts on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total cost of **A** is `=SUMIF(B2:B100;"A";A2:A100)` = -150

His cost to himself is `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A100;C2:C100)` = -105

That is, he needs to compensate

`=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A100;C2:C100)-SUMIF(B2:B100;"A";A2:A100)`
= -105-(-150)=**45**

Similarly for **B** - all costs are
`=SUMIF(B2:B100;"B";A2:A100)` = -10

spent on himself `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A100;D2:D100)`=-55,

must pay another

`=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A100;D2:D100)-SUMIF(B2:B100;"B";A2:A100)`
=-55-(-10)=**-45**

Comment: Yes! SUMPRODUCT was what I was looking for! Took some time to implement though. Adapting it for my actual spreadsheet, the formula wound up being `=SUMPRODUCT($B$3:INDIRECT("B"&$A$2+2),$G$3:INDIRECT("G"&$A$2+2))-SUMIFS($B$3:INDIRECT("B"&$A$2+2),$B$3:INDIRECT("B"&$A$2+2),"<0",$E$3:INDIRECT("E"&$A$2+2),U14)-SUMIFS($B$3:INDIRECT("B"&$A$2+2),$B$3:INDIRECT("B"&$A$2+2),"<0",$E$3:INDIRECT("E"&$A$2+2),U15)-SUMIFS($B$3:INDIRECT("B"&$A$2+2),$B$3:INDIRECT("B"&$A$2+2),"<0",$E$3:INDIRECT("E"&$A$2+2),U16)-17393.03`

Comment: @hiigaran Sorry, but it seems to me that using `OFFSET($B$3,0,0,$A$2)` instead of `$B$3:INDIRECT("B"&$A$2+2)` is a little easier for both humans and computers - the program will not need to convert the number of values ​​from cell A2 to text, create the text address of the last cell, convert the text to the real address of the last cell and then get the whole calculated range - too much action IMHO

Comment: Learned two things for the price of one! I appreciate that.